# Getting Python to read text written in cmd

Tags: python, cmd

Not sure if screwed up my python in some way, but simple code below not functioning and not sure how to fix.

Using windows the idea is to open "cmd" in type: `name.py books_looking_for` and with that get the python to get the word (books_looking_for in this case) and open a browser with that search.
Problem is that the python doesn't "find" the text.

Code below:

```
import webbrowser, sys

#Get text from cmd
address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    
webbrowser.open('https://satakirjastot.finna.fi/Search/Results?lookfor={}&type=AllFields&dfApplied=1&limit=20'.format(address))
```

Trying with

```
print(address)
print(type(address))
```

results are

`<class 'str'>`

Any ideas how to fix?
Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The code looks fine. Maybe there's really something wrong with your python installation.

Comment: Problem solved by uninstalling python completely and installing fresh. So something to do with that i suppose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you slicing `sys.argv` this way? try simply taking the first index:

```
#Get text from cmd
address = sys.argv[1]
    
webbrowser.open('https://satakirjastot.finna.fi/Search/Results?lookfor={}&type=AllFields&dfApplied=1&limit=20'.format(address))
```

Comment: But then there is nothing to `.join`, right?

Comment: I am still getting
IndexError: list index out of range
When I test print(len(address))
the result is 0, regardless how many words I type in cmd while calling the code

Comment: I am parsing this way to get all the words, if the name of book or author I am looking for is longer than a single word

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the Argumentparser from the beginning.

It gives you many advantages, eg. automatic validation options and a autogenerated help page.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

arg_parser = ArgumentParser(description='Run Webbrowser with args')
arg_parser.add_argument('address', help='Look for given address')
args = arg_parser.parse_args()
webbrowser.open('https://satakirjastot.finna.fi/Search/Results?lookfor={}&type=AllFields&dfApplied=1&limit=20'.format(args.address))
```

[Python Manual for ArgumentParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)